# Ubuntu 10.04 doesnt boot

Tags: boot-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't boot into a usable system anymore. What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/i-cant-boot-into-a-usable-system-anymore-what-should-i-do)

I am using ubuntu 10.04-03 in virtual box.

All of a sudden today it doesn't boots up and shows (initramfs) prompt as shown below. Is there anyway I can fix it as I got really important data in it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try booting your VM with an ISO of [Parted Magic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partedmagic/) and running a check and repair of the filesystem. It could be just a filesystem error.