# Failed 12.04 Install, Cannot Boot

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't boot into a usable system anymore. What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/i-cant-boot-into-a-usable-system-anymore-what-should-i-do)

Was running 11.10, but decided to upgrade to 12.04. After more than 12 hours, my Dell Inspiron 15R was,just hanging. Could not do anything. So tried to reboot, all I get now is flashing screen on boot, but nothing more. Tried hitting shift before ubuntu loads & then the 1st option but all I get is a purple screen. So tried recovery & can get to a prompt, but how to I now 'recover' so that I can boot (load grub)?

I managed to get it all up & running after remounting `/` as rw, then setting up my network and finally running `dpkg --configure -a`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.Please run an ubuntu live cd/usb and back up all your data first. A clean install is better than a painful upgrade.Do all your tweaks to recover the failed ubuntu feeling free as your data is safe.I dont know how to recover through a command prompt.U can update the grub from the live cd/usb too.

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall the grub loader. Use a live cd to get to terminal and use following code to mount your boot directory and reinstall grub loader

```
> mount /dev/your_boot_partiton /boot 
>grub-install --root-directory /boot /dev/hda
```

This will reinstall your grub. If you come up with an unsuccessfull attempt then I will recommend you to rienstall the Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try to check you permitions to /tmp folder. (After update, root folder because avaliable only for root)

This helped for me
Ctrl + Alt + F1
then login
and then 
$ sudo chmod 0777 -R /tmp