# So I tried to upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04, and now I'm at the command line in recovery mode. What can I do?

Tags: installation, 10.04, 12.04

I first made sure I had installed all available upgrades for 10.04, and checked that my Update Manager settings were right for showing the 12.04 upgrade, but I didn't see it.  (I did this yesterday.)  So I did a quick Google and found [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-a-from-10-04-lts-to-12-04-lts), and ran update-manager -d from the command line.  It went through the download, started installing, and at this point I wanted to make sure I didn't have any other processes running so I opened the system monitor from the taskbar, as well as a terminal.  These opened, but I noticed that the windows no longer had the minimize-maximize-close buttons, and moreover I couldn't close them from the bar at the bottom.  Nor at this point was I able to switch between desktops.  The install proceeded until it came to a console prompt.  I tried responding with the default (I.e., 'n' keyboard input) but the console didn't take the input; it was unresponsive.  So I restarted the computer and the bootup procedure (from GRUB, only 10.04 is shown in the menu) appeared to hang on the low-res screen 'Ubuntu' and the 5 progress dots.  So I've restarted and gotten to the command line in recovery mode.  What to do now? :(  NB gcc 4.6.3 is installed so I know the installation got at least that far.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/i-cant-boot-into-a-usable-system-anymore-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!  It's booting up fine now.

Comment: Then please mark this as solved / close it.