# Upgrade to 12.04 does not boot

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't boot into a usable system anymore. What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/i-cant-boot-into-a-usable-system-anymore-what-should-i-do)

I have upgraded to 12.04 via upgrade mamager.
I cannot get the image to boot (blank screen) after the grub menu.
grub seems OK.
I can get the previous unix version to run in recovery mode (rahter shaky).

Booting 12.04 in recovery mode displayes very early the message 
firewire_ohci: Failed to set link Power Status

There is no firewire installed on this acer travelmate 8210 to my knowledge....

Is it possible to disable firewire for booting?

Is it possible to downgrade again to the previosu version of Ubuntu?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add the boot option:
blacklist=firewire_ohci

http://nickhumphreyit.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-disable-loading-of-firewire-on.html

Comment: Thanks this seems to bring the boot process a bit further!

Comment: Thanks this seems to bring the boot process a bit further!

However it stops a t a later stage with the same error message (udev process?)
I cannot boot either from CD. It stops during the purple screen with the five moving dots.
I guess I have to clean install 11.10.... @nick humphrey