# How to recover a 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 installation?

Tags: data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't boot into a usable system after updates. What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/i-cant-boot-into-a-usable-system-after-updates-what-should-i-do)

Using an AMD 64-bit system.  I upgraded using package manager (i.e. on-line).  The desktop freezes after login.

How can I recover using a cd version?  I do get a response when selecting "Recovery Console" before logging in.  Perhaps there is a cryptic command that can help me get the system back on track?

Cheers,               ....Erik.

Comment: Would you please edit/update your question with more information?  What do mean that you *get a response when selecting "Recovery Console"*?? Can you provide more of a description? What is the hardware (motherboard and/or video adapter, if known) you attempted to update (from what? 11.10? 10.04?) to 12.04 on? Have you tried booting with any non-standard kernel options?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I fixed it.  See my posting today.

Comment: Please try and elaborate on how you solved your problem by providing a little brief solution and accept own answer. Thank you.