# How to recover from an upgrade failure?

Tags: unity, 12.04, compiz, gconf

Today I foolishly gave in to upgrade requests to 12.04 from 11.10 and now Im having a lot of issues with the unity interface where the previous version worked seamlessly.

After boot the following services are running:

- /usr/bin/compiz-decorator
- compiz
- unity-window-decorator
- unity-panel-service
- unity-application-daemon
- unity-music-daemon

The main problems are :

1. Every 30seconds or so all windows and menus disappear for a few
   seconds leaving just the background image
2. If the mouse goes over the task bar items on the top right of the screen it causes a segmentation fault of
   `unity.glib.dbusproxy "unity.glib.dbusproxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:257 cannot call method SetViewType proxy /com/canonical/unity/lens/commands does not exist`
   Window boarders disappear and I can't move or resize windows
3. If the mouse goes over the app menu on the left I get a compiz segfault
   composite sync not supported
   compiz[7361]: segfault at 0 ip ... sp ... error 4 in libunityshell.so[...]
4. The computer will not shut down when I select "shut down" from the task bar
   on the top right.

Ive tried a lot of different commands to try and fix this based on other related questions:

1. unity --reset
2. unity --replace
3. compiz --replace
4. metacity --replace&unity
5. compiz-decorator
6. gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
7. gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compizconfig-1
8. rm -rf ~/.gconf* ~/.gnome* ~/.metacity ~/.compiz ~/.conf*
9. disabling animation features etc... in gconf-editor but any changes
   cause a segmentation fault
   "gconf-client-lookup assertion failed"
10. changing CCSM settings (compiz config settings manager)
11. reverting to gnome-session-fallback but it's not possible due to a dependency issue
    "gnome-session : Breaks: unity-2d (< 5.4~) but 5.2.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed E: Error"

So Ive made zero progress. Any suggestions appreciated :)

I have an Intel atom netbook with 945GSE Express integrated graphics controller

-Damian

Comment: Before any more tweaks,do a clean back up of your valuable data and continue to recover it to its past.I would suggest a clean install as your upgrade process has failed.

Comment: Adding to what @beeju said, I would also suggest you do a backup at once you restore to that state that you what. The default backup program is a good one.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have my personal data backed up on another drive. I will try a fresh install this evening. What is the default backup program? Is there a way to store the current state of my system so that if some update fails I can just return to its previous working state?

Comment: possibly helpful, though not a duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/i-cant-boot-into-a-usable-system-anymore-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 1):

you should sign up for the known bug here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/993189?comments=all

Unity2d should work for you with no trouble at all