# System locks up at login after latest update on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lock-screen, lockup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't boot into a usable system after updates. What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/i-cant-boot-into-a-usable-system-after-updates-what-should-i-do)

For starters, I am a noob when it comes to Ubuntu and Linux but I am hopeful that I have the *light* and the error of my past MS ways.

After a recent update last week from 12.04 to 12.04.1,  my system now locks up at the login screen.  Before the update the system would run but must admit it ran EXTREMELY slow.

I have installed 12.04 on a Dell P4 2.4 GHz, 2 GB DDR RAM, 80 GB IDE HD and an integrated Intel 3D Extreme Graphics.

Any ideas on why now the system locking up at login screen? Appreciate any ideas and/or tips.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).