# New to Linux: troubleshooting help with Ubuntu 14.04 issues

Tags: 14.04, login, scripts, menu, popup-ads

I am new to Linux and I'm having several issues with my version of Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64-bit.

computer info: ASUS x200m touchscreen 11.6"
original os: windows 8
current os: ubuntu 14.04lts 64-bit

1. I can only use my computer by logging in through recovery mode. If I simply allow the computer to automatically boot up, then after the menu page, I hear the startup sound but the screen turns black.
2. Everything is too big for the screen; the resolution is too large but the settings can't be altered in a way that would fit the screen better.
3. I want to change the unity  menu to one that more resembles a Window's-style menu but I do not know how to do this.
4. I am continuously getting pop-ups asking me whether or not I want to stop the script. I don't even know what this means but it is very annoying.
5. I am getting popups when using certain websites especially google and facebook which I think may indicate a virus but I didn't think this was possible with Linux.

**Any help with any of these questions would be GREATLY appreciated!!**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please read the [Help](http://askubuntu.com/help) and accordingly ask one question at a time.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it for your main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying Ubuntu. :)

There's a lot to deal with here, so it's probably best to start with the fundamentals. Questions 1 and 2 make me suspect that the installation didn't go quite right. You're laptop uses integrated Intel graphics, which are well-supported in Linux, so it shouldn't be having issues with the resolution.

Are you dual-booting with Windows 8 or just using Ubuntu?

If you just want Ubuntu installed, then the remedy is simple - erase the hard disk and install Ubuntu again. If you're dual-booting, then things are little more complicated.

Once we establish this, then we can proceed further.

Comment: My computer is a dual boot. 
It used to work fine but one day I turned on my computer and the problem I mentioned in (1) happened.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Without knowing the details, I'd suggest that you try the procedure in [these answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/i-cant-boot-into-a-usable-system-after-updates-what-should-i-do) in the first instance. The first one shows you how to back up your files before reinstalling Ubuntu. (The answers are written for 12.04, but the procedure in 14.04 is essentially the same.)

If there's no option to automatically reinstall Ubuntu alongside Windows 8, you might need to select "Something else" in the installer. If you're not familiar with hard disk partitioning, it might be a good idea to take a look at step 6 of [this tutorial](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html). It explains how to set up the Ubuntu partitions before the installation continues. You'd need to delete the relevant ones before setting them up again.

Try that and see if you get a bootable system after reinstallation.