# ubuntu get pasword but not starting after update

Tags: 14.04, login

I updated my Ubuntu 14.04 but after update it not starting after login and the login screen page will repeat
thanks

Comment: not enough information provided. Can you log in into TTY? What does the Xorg log look like?

Comment: press Ctrl + alt + T and type in `sudo rm .Xauthority ` and reboot.

Comment: no! It dose not login. I update system and restart it but after restart and after giving my password nothing happen. only after some second the login page will repeat and ask my password again...

Comment: As @Jakuje said you need to look if TTY works. To access it please type `Ctr` + `alt` + `F1`. It will prompt you for login and password.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to an ownership or a permission issue: if you have access to TTY using Ctr + alt + F1 (or F2, F3 ... ,F6). Login there: type your login when prompted for it, hit `return`, you will then be prompted for your password. Type it and hit `return`. Once you successfully logged in, try the following solutions:

1. `.Xauthority` ownership issue

   - Type `ls -lah`.
   - Look at the line containing `.Xauthority`.
   - If it owned by `root` than type: `sudo chown YourUsername:YourUsername .Xauthority`
2. `.` ownership issue

   - Type `ls -lahr`.
   - Look at the line containing only `.`.
   - If it owned by `root` than type: `sudo chown YourUsername:YourUsername .`
3. `/temp` permission issue

   - Type `ls -ld /tmp`.
   - If the permission do no look like `drwxrwxrwt`
   - Type `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp`
4. Just try deleting `.Xauthority` (by typing `sudo rm .Xauthority`)
5. lightdm is acting up -> complete reinstall

   - Make sure you are connected to internet with DHCP on!
   - Log in in the TTY and type the following commands:
   - `sudo apt-get purge lightdm`
   - `sudo apt-get update`
   - `sudo apt-get install lightdm`
   - `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
   - `sudo shutdown -r now` #to restart the computer

Comment: thanks friends . what happen after delete .Xauthority? I don't want lose my information and my programs . excuse me I'm beginner in linux

Comment: You will not lose anything. The file will be recreated properly after rebooting the computer.

Comment: when I use tty I get: mohsen-system-prudect-name login:    and when I use your commands system wants password and i input password and system type: login incorrect

Comment: nothing happend. I cheked and did all even delete .xauthoruty but yet can't login

Comment: The `login incorrect` message means that either the login OR/AND the password is incorrect! Check for caps and use the numbers from the top instead of the numpad. The commands I gave you will prompt you for password because of the `sudo` requiring administrator rights. If you type the wrong password you will have the message `Sorry, try again`.

Comment: I did all of those that you told above. .xauthority and . both are mohsen mohsen. also /tmp permition is the same as you told. and i deleted .auhturity too but any way i have the problem as i had... what can i do any more?

Comment: Ok that's strange. When you are logged in in TTY mode, what happens if you type `sudo sevice lightdm restart`?

Comment: nothing!! only go to login page and ask password and the same problem. I enter password and after few second again back to login and ask me password

Comment: Ok. I added a 5th step in the answer that might help but you need a working Internet connection for it.

Comment: yes I have but I don't no how I can connect to it in tty envirenment

Comment: unfortunatly I go to recovery mode and use dpkg Icon. and now I have only a black scrin and can't login to tty too

Comment: I think I got lost my ubuntu!!!! how I can fix It?? without loosing my information and my programs

Comment: Ok. That is now a whole different problem. **Don't panic!** The easiest way is to **save** what you can from your documents and **reinstall Ubuntu**. You can find in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/126727/411540)  a step by step approach to save your `home` directory before reinstalling. If you have documents that you would like to keep in other folders, make sure to copy them as well. Take your time. You can also get a list from recently installed, updated... packages in `/var/log/dpkg.log*` and a history of apt-get in `/var/log/apt/history.log*` to help you restore most of them.