# Blank screen on Ubuntu 18.04 after change of number of CPU in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, cpu

Simple issue:

When I change the number of CPU assigned to my Ubuntu 18.04 guest system on VirtualBox (see screenshots below) the system will boot into a blank screen.

To define blank screen: When I start the system I see the Ubuntu logo with white points beneath (the bootspash screen) and after about 30 seconds nothing at all.

When I change the number of CPU back to 1 the systems starts without any problems.

Host system is Windows 10. Virtualization is enabled in BIOS and in VirtualBox settings.

Here is what I did so far:

[Blank Screen troubleshooting at the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen) - to complicated for me

[Boot the System with a LiveCD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/i-cant-boot-into-a-usable-system-after-updates-what-should-i-do) seems to be a good idea. [Download LiveCD](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and insert into VB guest via Settings -> Storage -> +CD

Unfortunate for me: also a blank screen :(

Any suggestions?

Screenshots:

[image: working configuration]

[image: not-working configuration]

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox]

[image: Virtualization enabled]